# What is the net weight and outside size of the iPad mini box when new?

Tags: ipad

What are the physical dimensions of one iPad mini box?

I want to order two iPads mini and then have them shipped in one box but I'm worried about the width, height, depth & size of the outer box because I'll do international shipping.

Precise measurements are very much appreciated as I wish to be specific about the rates & costs.

Comment: I had hoped to get the outer shipping shell to get you an answer, but have you been able to get someone that is selling them to answer this yet?

Comment: "When new"??? After songs, videos, and apps are put into it, it will weigh more, I guess???

Comment: @GEdgar Surely it does. `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the reference:**

**Length**: 21.3 CM 
**Width**: 14.7 CM 
**Height**: 3.3 CM 
**Gross Weight**: 0.5 KG

Answer (score 1):

- Length: 21.3 cm
- Width: 14.7 cm
- Height: 3.3 cm
- Gross weight: 0.5 kg

Answer (score 0):

I am ordering one, but it's en route so I can't measure but I can give you the shipping weight, from FedEx tracking, 1.6 lbs.

Mind you, that is actual shipping weight, including the additional outer packing materials covering the retail box. I believe the retail sealed box kit weighs 1.2 lbs. (gathering from various sources on the net).